# NPE on hasDeclaredProperty with Jena 2

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web

I'm getting started with Jena (using `com.hp.hpl.jena`), and I'm running into a weird problem.

I'm using a sample ontology, where an `Expert` has a `Name` as a string literal and `Research`es. I want to list the properties of an `Expert` using `OntClass.listDeclaredProperties()`, but it results in a `NullPointerException`. Here is the sample of the code:

```
        OntClass expert = model.getOntClass(ONTOLOGY_URL + "Expert");
        Iterator it = expert.listInstances();

        // print out the instances of the Expert class
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Individual oi = (Individual) it.next();
            System.out.println(oi.getLocalName());

            //get the properties of the instances of the Expert class
            Iterator ipp = expert.listDeclaredProperties(false); // NPE here
            while (ipp.hasNext()) {
                OntProperty p = (OntProperty) ipp.next();
                //print out property name and its values
                System.out.println(p.getLocalName());

                for (Iterator ivv = oi.listPropertyValues(p); ivv.hasNext();) {
                    String valuename = ivv.next().toString();
                    System.out.println(valuename);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntClassImpl.testDomain(OntClassImpl.java:940)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntClassImpl.hasDeclaredProperty(OntClassImpl.java:628)
    at com.richou.jenasandbox.client.Main.getProperty(Main.java:68)
    at com.richou.jenasandbox.client.Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: The stacktrace does not seem to align - listDeclaredProperties is not in the stack.

Comment: Do you have to use jena2, not jena3?